# Proof of trigonometric identity using vector calculus

Tags: trigonometry, vector-analysis

Question:
Using vector calculus, show that $\sin (A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$

I have no idea how to even attempt the question. A small hint to help me get started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I drew two vectors that make an angle A and B with their resultant. I tried taking components of one of the vectors along the other, but that didn't help me :/ @pbs

Comment: The vector calculus approach can be seen as a translation of $\cos(A+B)+i\sin(A+B)=e^{i(A+B)}=e^{iA}e^{iB}=(\cos(A)+i\sin(A))(\cos(B)+i\sin(B))$.

Comment: How are you using vectors to represent sine and consine? Also you are missing a $

Comment: @user166967 Ummm I drew two vectors that make an angle with their resultant? So taking components you get sine and cosine. And thanks for the heads up

Comment: @KimJongUn Ummm vector analysis would be a better term I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the unit vectors $\langle \cos(90-A), \sin(90-A)\rangle $ and $\langle \cos B, \sin B \rangle $

Take the dot product 
$$\langle \cos(90-A), \sin(90-A)\rangle \bullet  \langle \cos B, \sin B \rangle = \cos (90 -A -B) $$

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm..... So shouldn't I take the cross product? As I need sine?

Comment: That works too ! But the dot product is a bit simple to visualize for me :)

Comment: $$(a_1,a_2) \bullet  (b_1, b_2)  =  a_1b_1 + a_2b_2$$

Comment: But how would I get the identity for sine from that?

Comment: $\cos(90-A-B) = \cos (90 - (A+B)) = \sin(A+B) $

Comment: For the left side, use the previous dot product formula in coordinate plane :  $$(a_1,a_2) \bullet  (b_1, b_2)  =  a_1b_1 + a_2b_2$$

Comment: Yeah lol sorry.

Comment: no worries haha! the proof using complex numbers is more fun, look it up in goolge sometime :)

Comment: There's a proof for this using complex numbers?? But that must also use the polar form I take it?

Comment: Indeed it does use polar form and the euler's definition. its a simple proof :
$$ \begin{align} \\ \sin(A+B) &=  \mathcal{Img} \left(e^{i (A+B)}\right)\\&= \mathcal{Img} \left(e^{iA} . e^{iB}\right) \\&=  \mathcal{Img} \left( (\cos A + i\sin A) . (\cos B + i\sin B)\right) \\&=  \mathcal{Img} \left( \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B +  i(\sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B)\right) \\&= \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B \end{align} $$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\cos B&-\sin B\\\sin B&\cos B\end{pmatrix}$ is a counter-clockwise rotation by angle $B$. Apply it (via left-multiplication) to the point $\begin{pmatrix}\cos A\\\sin A\end{pmatrix}$. The result is $\begin{pmatrix}\cos (A+B)\\\sin (A+B)\end{pmatrix}$. But
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos B&-\sin B\\\sin B&\cos B\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos A\\\sin A\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B\\\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Don't understand it I'm afraid.

Comment: I expanded the post slightly. For intuition, draw the point $(\cos A,\sin A)$ in the plane. What will happen after you rotate that point counterclockwise by the angle $B$?

Comment: Ohhh.... I see what you did there now. But where did you get the matrix from? Any proof for that/

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix.

Comment: I see now. Very ingenious way of doing it. Any easier way to do it though?

Comment: I was a bit worried about circular reasoning: that the rotation matrix above must be derived using the trig sum identities. But look at the accepted answer in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53143/how-do-we-prove-the-rotation-matrix-in-two-dimensions-not-by-casework.