# Calculating the coordinate of a point on a circular path

Tags: calculus, geometry

Say that I have a circular path like this:

[image]

where I go from point $A(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ are known values to point $B(x,y)$. My aim here is calculate the coordinates of point $B$ (i.e. the values of $x$ and $y$). I know that radius is $R$ so I know that the length of arc $AB$ is $|AB|=R\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle at the origin; however I am not sure how I should calculate the coordinate of point $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the rotation formula and shift your origin at point O, so that:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha-x_O\\\beta-y_O\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha'-x_O\\\beta'-y_O\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain this in simple steps? I can not understand it in the form it is now. What are $\alpha$, $\alpha'$, $\beta$, $\beta'$, $x_0$, $y_0$, and $\theta$?

Comment: @user77791 $\alpha,\beta$ are coods of A and $\alpha',\beta'$ of B and $x_O,y_O$ of O, $\theta$ is angle AOB, and I have used matrices.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do you derive that formula?

Comment: @user77791 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53143/how-do-we-prove-the-rotation-matrix-in-two-dimensions-not-by-casework

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned the sense (clockwise or anticlockwise w.r.t. the origin O) hence there are two points on the circular arc on either side of point A$  (\alpha, \beta)$. Hence the you can select the point B$(x, y)$ on any side of point A $(\alpha, \beta)$ (of your choice) as follows

$$x=\alpha \cos\theta \pm \beta \sin\theta$$
On substituting the value of x co-ordinate, corresponding y co-ordinate of point B$(x, y)$ is calculated as follows 
$$y=\frac{(\alpha^2+\beta^2)\cos\theta-\alpha x}{\beta}$$
While, the radius $R$ of the circle centered at the origin 'O' is given as follows
$$R=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$$