# Using rotation matrix vs sin & cos

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

I am trying to understand when/why you would use the 2D rotation matrix vs just using $\cos$ and $\sin$ in order to change a point's position in 2D space.

For example, I have a straight line from point A and point B. I want to change the location of point B but keep it the same distance ($length$) away from point A so that the line would draw to point B's new position.

What would be the benefit of using the matrix below:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$$

...instead of just using:

$Bx = Ax + \cos(\theta) * length$

$By = Ay + \sin(\theta) * length$

Comment: One reason is that your "instead of " calculation produces the wrong answer.

Comment: It looks like you have a mistake in the two formulas.

Comment: Do you know how to multiply a matrix and a vector?

Comment: Well where did you even get this formula from? And why do you think it would rotate the point?

Comment: It not possible for x or y to remain the same after addition of cos(theta) or sin(theta), except for cos(theta) = 0 or sin(theta) = 0.

Comment: @abcdef: Try your proposed addition formula for some examples. Let's say you want to rotate the point by 0 degrees (i.e., it should stay the same). What happens with your formula? Compare this to multiplying the rotation matrix by the vector $[x, y]^T$. What expressions do you get for the new coordinates? Can you intuitively see why this would give a rotation, compared to the addition formula?

Comment: Have a look at these lectures on linear algebra given by a german mathematician ( H. Bachmann) working in Japan; in particular, you'll see that the columns of the matrix tell you how the basis vactors  < 1,0> and <0,1> are transformed under the rotation ; note that not all rotations have the same matrix; so knowing what the rotation does to the basis vectors ( through the matrix ) allows you to determine what rotation you are dealing with : <https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEaZuUNvNSmj4PWg9q0uz5auZ5u1LZySd>

Comment: You can try to check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53143/888233) for an insight about the derivation.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Paraphrasing your edited example: You calculate $B'$, the image of $B$ rotated about $A$ by angle $\theta$, via $$(B'_x,B'_y)=(A_x+|AB|\cos\theta,A_y+|AB|\sin\theta)$$ This works, *provided* that $B$ sits *to the right* of $A$; also, it requires calculating $|AB|$. So, the formula has limited applicability and requires more work. By contrast, the vector-matrix formula $$B'=A+R_\theta(B-A)$$ allows $B$ to lie *anywhere* relative to $A$, and it doesn't require distances. (Having an "algebraic expression" for $B'$  can also be convenient for combining operations and such.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Commenters have focused on the errors in the question, but let me try to address the question that I think OP was asking, namely "Why all this matrix stuff, eh?"

Frankly, for computer graphics in the plane, it's mostly interesting when you include a third coordinate, which allows you to include both rotation and translation in a single matrix-multiply-form. (We add a third coordinate of "1" to any $xy$-point, and then
$$
\pmatrix{x\\y\\1} \mapsto M\pmatrix{x\\y\\1}, \text{ where}\\
 M = \pmatrix{c & -s & a\\
s & c & b \\
0 & 0 & 1}
$$
rotates the point $(x, y)$ around the origin by angle $\theta$, where $c = \cos\theta$ and $s = \sin \theta$, and then translates the result by $(a, b)$.

(Changing the bottom two zeroes to nonzero values lets you do interesting keystoning things, but that's a whole other story.)

Now you could write that out as
$$
x' = cx - sy + a \\
y' = sx + cy + b
$$
equally well. No matrices in sight.

But suppose you then wanted to apply another rotation and translation by some different angle and translation-amount. You'd write $x'', y''$ in terms of $x', y'$, and to find $x'', y''$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, you'd have to do a substitution. Not too bad, but prone to errors, etc. Now imagine a chain of say, five of these...it starts looking like a nightmare, and the computations you have to do get messier and messier.
Contrast that to
$$
v \mapsto M_5 M_4 M_3 M_2 M_1 v.
$$
That looks like you have to multiply $v$ by five matrices, which is no better or worse than what you did before. But suppose you want to transform, say, 300 points, $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_{300}$. In that case, you can do something sneaky, because matrix-multiplication is *associative*. You can let
$$
N = M_5 M_4 M_3 M_2 M_1,
$$
which you compute *just once*, and then your transformation becomes
$$
v \mapsto Nv,
$$
saving you a ton of computation. This was the essence of the transformation hierarchies used in many early computer graphics systems.

The short answer to your question is then this:

If you need to transform multiple points by a sequence of transformations, it's useful to compose the sequence of transformations and then apply the *composed* transformation to each of the points.  Composing the transformations becomes easy when they're expressed using matrix multiplication, which has algebraic properties (like associativity) that aren't necessarily obvious from the written-out-equations form of the individual transformations.

Comment: As a sneaky added bonus, if there's any floating-point error creeping into the calculations, doing it via a single transformation on all the points helps ensure that at least the error is consistent which will reduce the risk of weird behaviours.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that using a rotation matrix to a local vector $(a,b)$ results in

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \Delta x = a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta \\
 \Delta y = a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta \\
 \end{aligned} $$

So the polar transform $(\ell \cos \theta, \ell \sin \theta)$ is equivalent to transforming the local vector $(\ell,0)$

$$\begin{aligned}
 \pmatrix{\Delta x \\ \Delta y} & = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\ell \\ 0} 
\end{aligned} = \pmatrix{ \ell \cos \theta \\ \ell \sin \theta}$$

So the rotation matrix is used when you know some local cartesian coordinates $(a,b)$ that need to be transformed to global coordinates, and the polar form is used when only one distance $\ell$ (along the local *x*-axis) needs to be rotated to the global coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :)